# Closed horseshoe magnet

Tags: magnet

If you would take a c shaped iron bar that you would join together (with threaded ends with another threaded bar for example) and then wind in wire, would it act like like a toroidal magnet or still like a horseshoe magnet since there's still gaps?

EDIT 2019-03-04: I've replaced "ring magnet" by the proper term "toroidal magnet"

[image]

Comment: If you short out the north and south poles with steel most of the magnetic field will be gone. Some U shaped magnets have a shorting bar built in, so it acts like an ON/OFF switch. Remove the shorting bar, and the magnet is full strength again. Only heat above the Curie temperature will permanently weaken a magnet.

Comment: what's a ring magnet?

Comment: Exactly, what is a ring magnet? There is not such a thing. A magnet by definition has poles. It is a fundamental assymetry between electric and magnetic fields. There are electrical charges but there are not magnetic monopoles, at least not in our everyday life. Maybe there were when the Universe was created.

Comment: Isn't a toroidal coil kind of a ring magnet?

Comment: Hello, tank you for the precision, it is indeed a toroidal magnet. I did not represented the wire coil on my drawing.